# How do I add execute permission to a file in CVS after it's already been checked in?

Tags: cvs

We use CVS on Linux for software development.

I noticed that one of the scripts I'm working on is missing the execute bit set in the CVS repository.

Is there any way to add the execute bit back to the file?

I think it involves modifying the repository directly, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modify the permissions of the related `,v` file in the repository.  Per [this article](http://i-proving.com/space/Technologies/CVS/CVSROOT+and+file+permissions), the file is checked out with the same permissions as the `,v` file in CVSROOT.

Comment: FYI I tried your link with my Firefox browser... it didn't work until I replaced the "%2B" with "+" directly in the address bar.

Comment: @Jin Kim, Thanks - I fixed the link.  It was some problem with the stackoverflow markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Cvs command option watch is also preventing file permissions to be restored. If watched, when file is checked out it will be read-only. From cvs man pages:

```
$ cvs watch --help_options

Usage: cvs watch {on|off|add|remove} [-lR] [-a <action>]... [<path>]...

on/off: turn on/off read-only checkouts of files
```

So, use `cvs watch off filename` to remove checkout from repository making it read only every time.