# How to control file permissions in CVS repository?

Tags: permissions, cvs

Currently some users have their umask set in ways which result in **execute permission on regular files, which I'd like to avoid**.

Is there a way to force all files checked in to only be read with some exceptions?

**What is the recommended way to handle this in CVS?**

Answer (score 1):

Cvs command option watch is also preventing file permissions to be restored. If watched, when file is checked out it will be read-only. From cvs man pages:

```
$ cvs watch --help_options

Usage: cvs watch {on|off|add|remove} [-lR] [-a <action>]... [<path>]...

on/off: turn on/off read-only checkouts of files
```

So, use `cvs watch off filename` to remove checkout from repository making it read only every time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best solution, but I would probably do something with the cvswrappers file in CVSROOT directory of the repo, using commitinfo, commitcheck and commit_prep.pl. If you don't have commit_prep.pl, you can use something like this one:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/cvs/cvs-29/cvs/contrib/commit_prep.pl

There are quite a few examples on the web, so just search for those commit* files if you don't already have those in your repo.

Note that, as this post suggests, the permission is really set only during the first commit of a file, after that, you'd need to "manually" modify the permission on the repository itself.

[How do I add execute permission to a file in CVS after it's already been checked in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710592/how-do-i-add-execute-permission-to-a-file-in-cvs-after-its-already-been-checked)

In commit_prep.pl, you can clear the exec permission using chmod ugo-x , before the file is committed for the first time.

This solution assumes you are using linux.