# Why does CVS change the protections on commit?

Tags: cvs

I have a file

`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ics ics 917 Aug  1 08:38 apply_ws_db_chgs.sh`

When I cvs commit this file, the file protections are stripped of x for owner, group, and other.

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 ics ics 972 Aug  1 08:43 apply_ws_db_chgs.sh`

What can I do to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710592/how-do-i-add-execute-permission-to-a-file-in-cvs-after-its-already-been-checked). I enetered this command in the CVS repository:

chmod 555 apply_ws_db_chgs.sh,v

Problem solved.